# Can't add social login with Google on Android - but on iOS it's working

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

I'm trying to add support to social login with Google on my application using the package [google_sign_in](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in).

I got to add support of that on iOS, and it's working. But on Google, for some unknown reason, it can't work anymore.
Few days ago it was working, but now it just start the following loading, and then shows the error **Couldn't sign in**:

[image]

[image]

On **OAuth consent screen**, since I updated some informations on my application, I needed to request again the authorization, but it says that the previous consent is still in use... but I don't know if would be the root of the problem and I really need to wait 4~6 weeks to work again on Android.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed. It was being caused by a wrong `jks` of Firebase.